# How should I find a Mongoose subdocument given the parent document and a value in the subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm just trying to do a basic find similar to `.findOne`, but on a subdocument array in Mongoose. Should I simply loop through the array looking for the right subdocument?

I have a schema like so:

```
var RegionSchema = new Schema({
  "metadata": {
    "regionType": String,
    "name": String,
    "children": [{
      "name": String,
      "childType": String
    }],
    "parent": Schema.ObjectId
  },

  "data": [DataContainer]
});
```

I know that I want to find a `DataContainer` in `data` with `dataYear` equal to `"2014"`. I'm new to MongoDB, so I don't know many advanced commands. What would be the most efficient way?

EDIT: `dataYear` is guaranteed to be unique in that array.

Comment: Can you also show `DataContainer` schema as well as a sample document with data?

Comment: It's pretty simple. For the purposes of this question `DataContainer` contains `population` (Number) and `dataYear` (String). `dataYear` is unique to each subdocument in an array. So it's not a big query.

Comment: @Antrikshy have you checked the suggested answer yet?

Comment: I ended up doing something else. Because I was dealing with smaller arrays, I made a function that just goes through and returns the index of the subdocument I was trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregation framework for this. Your aggregation pipeline would consist of a **`$match`** operation stage which matches documents in the collection where the data array element object has a field `dataYear` with value equal to `"2014"`. The next pipeline stage would be the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operation on the data array object and a further [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline to filter the arrays. Final stage would be to [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) the deconstructed array. For example, suppose you have a model `Region` that uses the `RegionSchema`, your mongoose code would be:

```
Region.aggregate([
    // similar query object you use in findOne() can also be applied to the $match
    {
        "$match": {
            "data.dataYear": "2014",
            "metadata.name": "example text" 
        }        
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$data"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "data.dataYear": "2014"
        }        
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "dataYear": "$data.dataYear",
            "population": "$data.population"
        }        
    }
], function(err, docs){

});
```

Comment: But I already have used `findOne` to get a single `Region` document and I just want to find a subdocument in `data` with that year. There may be other `Region`s with `data.dataYear == "2014"`, but I only want to look inside this one array.

Comment: @Antrikshy The query object you used in `Region.findOne({query})` is also applicable in the aggregation using the first `$match` operation pipeline stage. Try it, this will give you the subdocument you need. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to your query.

Assuming `Region` is the model:

```
Region.findOne(...).select({data: {$elemMatch: {dataYear: 2014}});
```

This will return the `Region` document with the `data` array containing only the matching item.

UPDATE: If you already have a document with an array of subdocuments you can use something like lodash's [`find`](https://lodash.com/docs#find) method to select the subdocument. NOTE: this will convert the subdocument to a POJO.

```
_.find(region.data.toObject(), {dataYear: 2014});
```

Comment: I said that I have the parent document and only need to look for a subdocument inside this parent.

Comment: So you still want the entire array as well? Sorry, that wasn't clear in your original question. The only matching method Mongoose has for subdocumnets is an [`id`]() method which is only useful if you know the id of the subdocument. Since you are using another field for matching you will have to use an external solution to do so. Updating my answer to show an example.